# Erro ao conectar PHP ActiveRecord com XAMPP phpmyadmin

Tags: php, xampp, active-record

Ao tentar conectar o phpactiverecord ao banco de dados no XAMPP phpmyadmin por meio deste código:

```
<?php

require_once 'php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

$cfg = ActiveRecord\Config::instance ();
$cfg->set_model_directory ( 'model' );
$cfg->set_connections ( array ('development' => 'mysql://root@localhost/phpmyadmin/dbaqua') );
```

Recebe-se a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException'
with message
  "exception 'PDOException'
   with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'phpmyadmin/dbaqua'"
in C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php:202
>Stack trace:
>0 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php(202): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', NULL, Array)
>1 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php(99): ActiveRecord\Connection->__construct(Object(stdClass))
>2 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\ConnectionManager.php(33): ActiveRecord\Connection::instance('development')
>3 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(83): ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::get_connection(NULL)
>4 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(61): ActiveRecord\Table->__construct('UsuarioModel')
>5 C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\M in C:\xampp\htdocs\BancoAQUA\service\library\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php on line 204
```

Como isso pode ser solucionado? Desde já obrigada.

UsuarioModel:

```
<?php

require_once 'settings/config.php';

class UsuarioModel extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'tdusuario';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **phpmyadmin NÃO é** um banco de dados, ele é apenas um gerenciador, as suas aplicações PHP não controlam ele, pois ele já é uma aplicação e não é usada pelo usuário final de uma aplicação é usado apenas por quem gerencia o banco pra facilitar a "manutenção".

Recomendo que leia:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)
- [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635)

O protocolo `mysql:` não acessa urls como http, que parece que foi o que você tentou em `mysql://root@localhost/phpmyadmin/dbaqua`

Conforme a documentação http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Quick_Start o correto é:

> mysql://[USUARIO]:[PASSWORD]@[HOST]/[NOME DO BANCO]

Então se o nome do seu banco é `dbaqua`:

```
<?php
require_once 'php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg)
{
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => 'mysql://root@localhost/dbaqua')
    );
});
```

> Nota: Xampp não é um servidor, ele é um pacote que acompanha o Apache (esse sim é o servidor) + PHP + mysql, você não se conecta ao Xampp, você se conecta ao Apache ou ao Mysql (depende do que esta fazendo)

Comment: Muito Obrigada Mesmo!!!

Comment: @Beatriz se resolveu por favor marque a resposta como correta ;)