# Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, easyphp

Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?

- Eles todos são servidores?
- São todos PHP oficiais?

Comment: Eu particularmente gosto dessa pergunta, eu já tive essa dúvida há um bom tempo e na época penei um pouco para descobrir, se tivesse algo assim naquela época teria me ajudado muito. Tem certeza que o motivo pelo qual quer remover é esse mesmo que você falou? Eu discordo.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Muitos acham que existem diferenças entre wamp, xampp e php, que são servidores "distintos"

### O que são pacotes prontos

O wamp, zwamp, xampp e easyphp **não são "servidores"** são pacotes de instalação com uma série de programas que incluem:

- apache (servidor HTTP)
- mysql (servidor de banco de dados que roda em uma porta separada e apenas acompanha mas não está ligado diretamente)
- php (linguagem dinâmica que rodará junto ao servidor HTTP por apache2handler ou fastcgi)

Então eles são pacotes que pré-instalam apache, mysql e php e geralmente acompanham de um "dashboard" pra Desktop que controla todos os 3, alguns deles instalam mais que php, apache e mysql.

### Diferenças entre wamp, zwamp, xampp e easyphp

- O wamp é somente para Windows e instalação acompanha PHP, Apache, mysql, phpmyadmin e tem pacotes para versões de processadores x86 e x64.

  <sub>(extra: Uma versão dele suporta PHP5.6 e PHP7, podendo alternar)</sub>

  > W.A.M.P significa: **W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ysql/**M**ariaDB, **P**HP
- O zwamp (parece estar descontinuado), acompanha Apache, MySQL, PHP, MiniPerl, MongoDB, XCache, Adminer (semelhante ao phpmyadmin) e PHP MongoDB (semelhante ao phpmyadmin mas pra mongodb), ele é somente pra windows e tem pacotes para versões de processadores x86 e x64

  > Z.W.A.M.P significa: **Z**ero-install, **W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ysql/**M**ariaDB, **P**HP
- Xampp suporta Windows, Mac OSX, distros Linux, Solaris, acompanha PHP, mysql, Apache, mariadb (ou mysql), perl, phpmyadmin e uma série de outros programas e tem pacotes para versões de processadores x86 e x64 variando conforme o sistema operacional.

  <sub>(extra: Uma versão dele suporta PHP7)</sub>

  > X.A.M.P.P significa: **X** (qualquer sistema), **A**pache, **M**ysql/**M**ariaDB, **P**HP e **P**erl
- O EasyPHP, até o nome já diz se traduzirmos, seria algo como *php fácil*, ou melhor *php descomplicado*! Ele tem os seguintes pacotes PHP, Apache, MySQL, Nginx (alternativa ao apache, pode alternar entre ambos), PhpMyAdmin, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Python, Ruby e roda apenas em Windows, tem pacotes para versões de processadores x86 e x64.

  <sub>(extra: Uma versão dele suporta PHP7 e também pode ser interessante pra quem quer instalar Ruby em Windows, pois a instalação manual as vezes é complicada)</sub>

### wamp, zwamp, xampp e easyphp são oficiais do php.net?

PHP é um programa que interpreta scripts da linguagem php (a extensão pode ser customizada) tanto por servidores web quanto por linha de comando ou porta CGI, não o wamp, zwamp, xampp e easyphp não são oficiais do php, na verdade você pode baixar o php, mysql e apache isoladamente e criar o seu próprio pacote ou servidor. O wamp, zwamp, xampp e easyphp são nada mais que **"facilitadores de instalação"** que geralmente contem um painel de controle pra facilitar também e são mantidos por pessoas diferentes.

Note que em sistemas linux como Ubuntu e Debian você não precisa instalar o Xampp, você pode usar simplesmente o `apt-get` e ele vai baixar dos repositórios. Então wamp, zwamp, xampp, easyphp e instalação por repositórios são nada mais que pacotes de instalação que as vezes veem acompanhados de algumas ferramentas extras, tudo pra facilitar apenas.

### O PHP é um servidor?

O PHP é um interpretador de "scripts php", no entanto a partir da versão PHP5.4 ele pode sim ser usado como servidor independente, mas não pra produção e sim apenas pra o ambiente de desenvolvimento, fazendo assim o Apache ser "desnecessário" em alguns casos e ele pode funcionar com [Built-in web](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), digite no cmd:

```
cd C:\User\Usuario\Documents\projeto1
php -S localhost:8000
```

ou terminal:

```
cd ~/projeto1
php -S localhost:8000
```

E depois no navegador acesse `http://localhost:8000`, pronto você tem um servidor de desenvolvimento baixando apenas o PHP sem precisar instalar mais nada, claro que se for precisar de mysql por exemplo vai precisar baixar, mas você pode baixar ambos isoladamente e instalar:

- http://php.net/downloads.php
- https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Todavia usar `.htaccess` com ele não irá funcionar, apesar de ser possível simular com o "router" do php. O principal fundamento do PHP é executar os scripts PHP.

### Extra:

Pra entender a diferença de phpmyadmin e mysql leia a seguinte pergunta:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Comment: Creio que seja uma boa colocar o significado das siglas: WAMP: Windows + Apache + Mysql + PHP; XAMPP: uniX + Apache + Mysql + PHP + ???