# É possível enviar email com xampp de um servidor local?

Tags: php, apache, email, xampp, wamp

Bom, de vez em quando, me encontro numa seguinte situação em que não posso fazer o teste de sites/sistemas que desenvolvo. Praticamente sempre, desenvolvo o sistema na minha máquina, para depois subir para um servidor de hospedagem.

Eu prefiro sempre antes testar tudo, para fazer o upload do site/sistema praticamente "pronto", com tudo testado. O **envio de email** é uma exceção que ainda não consegui resolver.

Quero saber se tem como enviar emails da minha aplicação php para testar essa funcionalidade (independente do plugin, como phpmailer por exemplo), somente usando xampp da minha máquina local, ou seja, sem um domínio propriamente dito e sem um servidor de hospedagem.

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite! pode começar com: [Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40858/91)

Comment: opa, show, não tinha visto algo aqui, e olha que procurei :(

Comment: rray então independe do servidor né, xampp, wampp, easyphp, dá na mesma né

Comment: sim @DiChrist, serve para qualquer um. Veja a resposta que postei.

Comment: A configuração é feita no php.ini, tem uma outra pergunta interessante caso não tenha visto, [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/91) :)

Comment: vou testar ela amanhã, hoje não terei tempo, estou precisando solucionar esse problema

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: rray só pude pegar isso agora hahaha, neste exato momento estou testando

Answer (score 2):

Sim, pois uso isso aqui. Basta editar no php.ini apontando para um servidor de email qualquer que você use:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
//MEU IP INTERNO, MAS PODE USAR O SMTP DO GMAIL, YAHOO, UOL...
SMTP = 192.168.203.55 
; http://php.net/smtp-port
//A PORTA COM AUTENTICAÇÃO É OUTRA
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = SEUENDEREÇO@SEUPROVEDOR.COM.BR
```

Answer (score 2):

Como é independente do script que vai utilizar, apenas utilize os dados de uma conta do Gmail, por exemplo:

```
Servidor: smtp.gmail.com
Porta: 465 (SSL) ou 587 (TLS)
Usuário: seuemail@gmail.com
Senha: Sua senha
```

O limite é de 2.000 envios diários. Mais detalhes dos limites aqui: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852

Configurações do envio: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR