# Falha de download ao tentar atualizar plugins no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Fiz a instalação do Wordpress localmente, instalei alguns plugins e agora estou tentando atualizar as traduções. O que acontece é que ele não atualiza.

*Obs:* uso EasyPHP e WP 4.6.1

Ele exibe a seguinte mensagem:

> Falha no download. No working transports found

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: EasyPHP não é servidor é apenas um gerenciador/facilitador, ele tecnicamente não faz nada além de instalar o Apache, PHP e mysql de forma mais simples na sua máquina, recomendo que leia isto para entender a diferença primeiro http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O *Wordpress* usa as extensões Curl e Openssl para fazer download dos plugins, no caso as extensões estavam desativadas assim:

Se for windows:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Se for like-unix (por exemplo linux, mac osx, bsd):

```
;extension=curl.so
;extension=openssl.so
```

A extensão Curl serve para acessar páginas via HTTP e a extensão Openssl serve para acessar que o Curl consiga acessar páginas HTTPS, os plugins do Wordpress estão em nos servidores/repositórios do Wordpress e estão sob o protocolo `https://`, para que o PHP consiga baixar é necessário ter ambas extensões ativadas, para isto basta remover o ponto-e-virgula (`;`) da frente e reiniciar o Apache em seguida.

Se for Windows deixe assim:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Se for like-unix (linux, mac osx, bsd):

```
extension=curl.so
extension=openssl.so
```

Lembre-se, para que tenha efeito deve reiniciar o Apache (ou Nginx)

---

### Como reiniciar o Apache/Nginx

Se for Windows e Mac vai depender muito de com instalou, se foi manualmente ou se foi com pacotes prontos e se ele foi instalado como serviço ou não

Para reiniciar o Apache no Linux:

- Geralmente Red Hat:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- No Suse:

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
  ```
- Outras distros:

  ```
  sudo restart apache2
  ```

  ou:

  ```
  sudo apache2 restart
  ```

  > **Nota:** Se o caminho do Apache não estiver Global talvez tenha que digitar assim `/etc/init.d/apache2`, mas depende de onde foi instalado

Reiniciar Nginx:

- No Ubuntu geralmente:

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart nginx
  ```
- Outras distros:

  ```
  sudo service nginx restart
  ```

  ou:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
  ```

Comment: Excelente, funcionou perfeitamente, ficou bem claro a explicação, obrigado novamente ;D