# PHP - Como enviar requisição em segundo plano ( API HTTP SMS )

Tags: php, html, sms

Estou fazendo um formulário o qual assim que é enviado, ele deve enviar um SMS agradecendo pelo contato para o número no qual foi informado no formulário.

> Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="processa.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Mensagem:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Enviar sua mensagem</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

> Arquivo - processa.php

```
<?php
    $email              = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $nome               = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $telefone           = addslashes($_POST['telefone']);
    $mensagem           = addslashes($_POST['mensagem']);

    $destinatario    = "meuemail@gmail.com";
    $assunto         = "Nova solicitação de contato";
    $msg             = "
Você recebeu a seguinte solicitação de contato:
-------------------------------------
Nome: $nome
Email: $email
Telefone: $telefone
Mensagem: $mensagem  ";

    $headers         = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
    $headers        .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers        .= "From: NOME DO CONTATO <contato@contato.com>\r\n"; // remetente
    $headers        .= "Return-Path: contato@contato.com\r\n"; // return-path
    $envio           = mail($destinatario, $assunto, $msg, $headers);

    if($envio){
       header ("location: sucesso.html"); 
    }else{
     echo "A mensagem não pode ser enviada";
    } 
?>
```

O formulário quando é preenchido, ele me envia um e-mail com os dados que foram inseridos, e em seguida redireciona para `sucesso.html`.

Gostaria que quando a pessoa submetesse o formulário, fosse enviado um SMS para a pessoa que preencheu o formulário.

**API HTTP - [Exemplo de utilização](http://gtisms.com/pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/HTTP_API_GTISMS_v1.6.pdf)**

`http://portal.gtisms.com:2000/gti/API/send.aspx?user=teste@dominio.com&senha=teste&msg=Obrigado+Por+Entrar+Em+Contato&n=11984010101&id=0001`

> Como adaptar o **script PHP** para que ele faça uma requisição para a **API HTTP** enviando um SMS para o número fornecido? O número (**$telefone**) deve ser atribuído ao parâmetro **`n=`**.
> Gostaria de um exemplo =(

Comment: Expecificamente essa API nunca usei, mas usei esta https://www.nexmo.com/. Para isso podes usar curl, http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Comment: Não entendi qual seria a dúvida, você pode usar o CURL, como mencionado. Se você quer reduzir o tempo resposta pode usar o `exec` com um CURL ignorando a resposta, assim a página será processada sem aguardar o curl. Enfim, a pergunta ficou meio vaga.

Comment: Tenta com file_get_contents passando essa url.

Comment: Se você realmente precisa despachar a resposta imediatamente e continuar processando o script após feito isso, leia a resposta do vcampitelli aqui no Stack Overflow em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response

Comment: Obrigado amigos, vou dar uma olhada pra ver se consigo fazer algo =/

Answer (score 2):

Conheçe [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)? Deve ficar assim:

```
$sms_user = 'teste@dominio.com';
$sms_msg = 'Obrigado Por Entrar Em Contato';
$sms_senha = 'senha';

$sms_telefone = preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', $telefone); //Remove todos caracteres que não forem números

//Codifica para url os dados
$sms_user = urlencode($sms_user);
$sms_msg = urlencode($sms_msg);
$sms_senha = urlencode($sms_senha);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://portal.gtisms.com:2000/gti/API/send.aspx?user=' . $sms_user . '&senha=' . $sms_senha . '&msg=' . $sms_msg . '&n=' . $sms_telefone . '&id=0001');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
    echo 'Erro ao executar o CURL: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode !== 200) {
        echo 'Erro ao requisitar o servidor';
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

//Depurar a saida:

var_dump($data);
```

Se não tem o curl ativado, veja nesta resposta como fazer https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169474/3635

**Note** que adicionei `var_dump`, mas quando estiver em **produção** você deve remove-lo.

Comment: Conhecia só por nome Gui, muito obrigado pela resposta, vou testar!!! =D =D =D