# Erro ao instalar tema no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

To usando wordpress localmente com EasyPHP, quando tento instalar um tema, plugin ou atualização é exibida a seguinte mensagem de erro:

*Falha no download. No working transports found*

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente este erro ocorre porque a extensão `php_curl`está desativada no webserver. Para conseguir realizar a instalação, basta ativa-la, porém ao realizar uma pesquisa rápida, parece que alguns usuários apresentaram algumas dificuldades.

Aqui tem uma pergunta muito similar a sua:

- [Falha de download ao tentar atualizar plugins no Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169467/falha-de-download-ao-tentar-atualizar-plugins-no-wordpress)

Em inglês:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905939/activation-curl-on-easyphp