# Como preencher campo input e submeter form com cURL?

Tags: php, libcurl

Como eu faço para preencher o **input** e realizar **submit** do **form** desse site https://appear.in/ usando cURL?

Quero usar o sistema de vídeo chat desse site no meu projeto, é bem simples criar uma nova sala de chat, porém no meu projeto eu preciso que isso seja feito automático pelo sistema.

Comment: Você sabe que isto é um método GET né? Você precisa apenas acessar o URL, por exemplo, `https://appear.in/Rodrigo-Fontes`. Quando você "algo" vai direto para "/algo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu recomendo usar a API oficial deles que é JavaScript https://developer.appear.in, adicione no seu HTML isto (tem que rodar no protocolo HTTP ou HTTPS, file talvez não suporte):

```
<script src="//developer.appear.in/scripts/appearin-sdk.0.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

E depois chame isto:

```
var AppearIn = window.AppearIn || require('appearin-sdk');
var appearin = new AppearIn();

// verifica se o navegador usa WebRTC
var isWebRtcCompatible = appearin.isWebRtcCompatible();

if (isWebRtcCompatible) {
    //Cria uma sala
    appearin.getRandomRoomName().then(function (roomName) {
        //Após iniciar a sala
    });
}
```

Se tiver uma sala especifica faça assim:

```
<iframe id="meu-iframe"></iframe>
```

E no JavaScript isto:

```
var minhaSala = "rodrigo-fontes";
appearin.addRoomToElementById("meu-iframe", minhaSala);
```

Mas se ainda sim você necessita do PHP por algum motivo, tipo criar salas dinamicamente, o uso do curl é relativamente simples, aparentemente tem que usar HTTPS, então faça assim:

```
$nomedasala = 'nome da sala';

$url = 'https://appear.in/' . urlencode($nomedasala);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Se der alguma mensagem de erro sobre SSL ou HTTPS então é porque o teu servidor está desligado, precisa habilitar o modulo de SSL, veja como fazer aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169474/3635

Mas se não conseguir de maneira alguma pode simplesmente desligar a checagem (o que não recomendo):

```
//Desliga
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Comment: Com a utilização da API está tudo OK. Mas quando fui realizar o teste com **cURL** não exibiu nada na tela, ficou simplesmente em branco, então dei um `var_dump($data)` e acabou aparecendo um monte de caracteres e pontos de interrogação. Eu apenas utilizei o seu código em um arquivo PHP sem nenhuma estrutura HTML. Poderia me ajudar?!

Comment: @RodrigoFontes eu só mostrei como gerar a sala, exibir na tela não tem muito sentido, afinal vai dar vários problemas com CORS, o melhor nesse caso é trocar por um iframe, por exemplo `<iframe src="https://appear.in/rodrigo-fontes"></iframe>`

Comment: Com o `iframe` funcionou (hehe), mas com o gz_decode deu **HTTP ERROR 500**. Mas teria alguma forma de redirecionar ou abrir em uma nova aba a sala no próprio site da appear.in, ao invés de carregar em um iframe?

Comment: Com o `var_dump(gzdecode($data));` quase funcionou. Quando você diz que "Não iria funcionar devido a bloqueios" você se refere ao erro da imagem asseguir: [imgur]: http://i.imgur.com/O4kCciJ.png . Só fica tentando conectar mais não acontece nada (isso utilizando o `gzdecode`).

Comment: @RodrigoFontes preste atenção por favor, os scripts executam funções de conexão, eles são liberados para rodar no dominio de origem, no caso  os scripts veem do dominio `appear.in`, se tentar injetar em outro dominio coisas como Ajax não irão funcionar devido a questões de segurança do proprio navegador. Outra coisa que pode ocorrer são URLs relativas não serem encontradas, pois se vc usar curl o dominio vai ser outro e o apontamento de tags como `<link>` e `<script>` não vai encontrar os resources. Espero que tenha ficado claro ;)

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, me ajudou muito! Consegui criar a sala com cURL e fazer redirecionamento com header('Location: '), vai funcionar para o que preciso.