# transferencia de um banco de dados para o outro

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site imobiliario, porém ele ja existe ou seja eu vou apenas atualiza-lo, minha duvida é saber  se é possivel transferir os imóveis ja cadastrados no site antigo para o novo ou é impossivel?

**obs: o site foi desenvolvido em WordPress**

Comment: Depende kkk sua pergunta não esta clara o suficiente para gerar uma boa resposta.

Comment: kkk, vou tentar explicar melhor, o site que eu desenvolvi é em php e o site antigo é o WordPress, sendo assim queria saber se é possivel transferir os imóveis que ja estão cadastrados no site antigo para o site atual

Comment: exporta o banco do site antigo, e depois importa para o novo site.  Veja se esse tutorial vai te ajudar  https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigada

Comment: O wordpress esta instalado no teu servidor ou esta usando direto pelos serviços do https://br.wordpress.com/create/?

Answer (score 3):

O banco de dados não esta ligado com o Wordpress e nem com o PHP "diretamente", isto deve explicar algumas coisas:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)
- [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635)

Resumindo o PHP é a linguagem que usada junto com o Apache ou Ngnix gera páginas dinamicas, Mysql é um servidor totalmente a parte e o PHP faz acesso a este servidor através de uma requisição TCP e usa a API para facilitar, ou seja você pode acessar o banco de dados do *Wordpress* sem precisar do *Wordpress*.

A única questão é como fará a leitura dos dados, o banco do *Wordpress* é bem especifico, o diagrama do banco é este:

[image: WP diagrama]

Então basta montar os SELECTs como desejar, alguns detalhes sobre as tabelas https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Um exemplo bem simples do uso da API mysqli para acessar o banco no seu servidor mysql:

```php
<?php
$host = 'mysql.servidor.com'; //endereço do seu host
$user = 'usuario';            //usuario do banco do Wordpress
$pass = 'senha';              //senha do banco do Wordpress
$banco = 'banco_wordpress';   //nome do banco do Wordpress

//Conecta
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $banco);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Erro de conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts'; //Seleciona dados da tabela wp_posts (provavelmente contem seus imóveis)

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    //... pega os dados
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Então se não sabe ainda o básico do uso PHP recomendo que comece pela documentação, segue os links:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Muito obrigada.