# Não consigo usar a var global $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Tags: php

Estava tentando fazer redirecionamento, pegando o caminho da url usando var global `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, mas sem sucesso.

Ao dar `print_r($_SERVER);`, vi que o  PATH_INFO não era mais listada.

ex.:

> 127.0.0.1:8080/edsa-Site/index.php

No caso queria pegar a parte "/index.php". Como poderei fazer isso, e se possível pegar somente "index" ?

Answer (score 2):

A variavel `PATH_INFO` é até comum em Apache, mas nem todo servidor vai possuir ela, pois ela nem sempre é configurado (dependendo de cada servidor), basicamente tem que configura-la manualmente, no seu caso provavelmente você esta usando php-built-in-server, sendo o caso ou não para obter o caminho pode usar o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

O "problema" do `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` é que ele retorna a querystring também, por exemplo se a URL for assim:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/edsa-Site/index.php?foo=bar
```

Vai retornar isto:

```
/index.php?foo=bar
```

E claro, isto é bem mais que o caminho, para resolver isto pode usar `explode`, `preg_replace`, `substr`+`strpos`, mas minha sugestão é usar algo mais simples, o `strtok`, ficando algo como:

```
$requri = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');

var_dump($requri);
```

Comment: Fiz o teste no servidor embutido do php, e deu certo, agora usando o Devserver 17 já não consigo usar o PATH_INFO. Existe algum meio de configurar o mesmo para poder usar?Quero poder fazer uns testes, mas preciso usar um banco de dados, e com o servidor embutido no php não consigo fazer o uso de uma database até onde sei.

Comment: @Medivh devserver17 nem é um servidor, é um pacote de programas recomendo que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115690/3635 ... não precisa usar PATH_INFO, usa o código que esta na resposta.